The problem of matching the dimensions of matrices in matrix multiplication in graph attention network
I want to use the following code to create a graph attention network whose nodes are the feature matrix and whose edges are the similarity matrix., but I have encountered this error:
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (625x2 and 50x1)
# Define the attention layer of the graph
class GraphAttentionLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features, out_features):
        super(GraphAttentionLayer, self).__init__()
        self.in_features = in_features
        self.out_features = out_features
        self.linear = nn.Linear(in_features, out_features)
        self.W = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(in_features, out_features))
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.W.data, gain=1.414)
        self.a =nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(2*out_features, 1)) 
    
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.a.data, gain=1.414)
        
        print("size self.a =",self.a.shape)
        print("size self.W=",self.W.shape)

    def forward(self, h, adj):
        h = self.linear(h)
        Wh = torch.matmul(h, self.W)
        a_input = self._prepare_attentional_mechanism_input(Wh)
        print("size a_input =", a_input.shape)
        e = F.leaky_relu(torch.matmul(a_input, self.a).squeeze(2))
        zero_vec = -9e15 * torch.ones_like(e)
        attention = torch.where(adj > 0, e, zero_vec)
        attention = F.softmax(attention, dim=1)
        attention = F.dropout(attention, training=self.training)
        h_prime = torch.matmul(attention, Wh)
        return F.elu(h_prime), attention

    def _prepare_attentional_mechanism_input(self, Wh):
        N = Wh.size(0)
        Wh_i = Wh.repeat(1, N, 1).view(N * N, -1)
        Wh_j = Wh.repeat(N, 1, 1).view(N * N, -1)
        all_combinations_matrix = torch.cat([Wh_i, Wh_j], dim=1)
        return all_combinations_matrix.view(N, N, -1)

# Model training function
def train_graph_attention_model(feature_matrix, similarity_matrix, labels, n_classes=4, epochs=10):
    model = GraphAttentionLayer(in_features=feature_matrix.shape[1], out_features=feature_matrix.shape[1])
    classifier = nn.Linear(train_feature_matrix.shape[1], n_classes)
    optimizer = optim.Adam(list(model.parameters()) + list(classifier.parameters()), lr=0.01)
    loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    attention_weights = []
    for i in range(feature_matrix.shape[0]):
        feature = feature_matrix[i]
        similarity = similarity_matrix[i]
        
        #Get the label for the current graph
        label = labels[i]
        label_tensor = torch.tensor([label], dtype=torch.long)

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            model.train()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
        
            output, attention = model(feature, similarity)
            output = output.mean(dim=0).unsqueeze(0)
            output = classifier(output)
        
            loss = loss_function(output, label_tensor)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
        
            if epoch == epochs - 1:
                attention_weights.append(attention.cpu().detach().numpy())

    return attention_weights

# Graph Attention drawing function
def plot_attention_graph(attention_weights):
    G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(attention_weights)
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
    nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_color='skyblue', node_size=700, edge_color='k', linewidths=1, font_size=15, arrows=True, edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
    plt.show()

# Define training data and similarity matrix
train_feature_matrix = torch.tensor(train_feature_matrix, dtype=torch.float) # train feature matrix
train_similarity_matrix = torch.tensor(train_correlation_matrix, dtype=torch.float) # train similarity matrix
train_labels = torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.long) # train labels 

#Specify the desired size for the labels
desired_size = 4096

#The number of current elements
current_size = train_labels.size(0)

# Check if the current number of elements is greater than the desired size
if current_size > desired_size:
    # Generate random numbers for sampling
    random_indices = random.sample(range(current_size), desired_size)

    # Sampling train_labels using random numbers
    reduced_labels = train_labels[random_indices]
else:
    reduced_labels = train_labels
    
print("train_feature_matrix:" , train_feature_matrix.shape)
print("train_similarity_matrix",train_similarity_matrix.shape)
print("train_labels",reduced_labels.shape)

# Teaching the graph attention model and receiving attention weights
attention_weights = train_graph_attention_model(train_feature_matrix, train_similarity_matrix, reduced_labels)

# Drawing graph attention using attention weights
plot_attention_graph(attention_weights)


The dimensions of the matrices used in the code:
train_feature_matrix= torch.Size([2939, 25])
train_similarity_matrix= torch.Size([2939, 2939])
train_labels = torch.Size([4096])
size self.a = torch.Size([50, 1])
size self.W = torch.Size([25, 25])
size a_input = torch.Size([25, 25, 2])

I changed the dimensions of self.a , a_input but the problem was not solved.

Error raised when you multiply a_input by self.a, which may be solved if you change shape of self.a to [2, out_features]
